# Разбираемся с .htaccess и регулярными выражениями на примере

Tags: регулярные-выражения, .htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с примером файла **.htaccess**.

Дальше я буду изменять его по аналогии, разбираться и понимать. Но вообще начать надо с чего-то конкретного же :)

Итак, есть вот такой .htaccess, взятый со [страницы поддержки хостинга](http://hosting.nic.ru/faq/dns.shtml).

```
(1) RewriteEngine On
(2)     
(3) RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /subdmn/[^/]
(4) RewriteRule ^subdmn/[^/]+/(.*) /$1 [R=permanent,L]
(5)
(6) RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.mysite\.tld$ [NC]
(7) RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.tld$ [NC]
(8) RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdmn
(9) RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdmn/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

При помощи PHP-модуля **mod_rewrite** эти настройки позволяют открывать файлы из каталога 
**\subdmn\XXXXXX** по адресу **XXXXXX.mysite.com**

**Просьба I:** Расскажите, пожалуйста, по шагам, что и в каком порядке происходит, когда пользователь набирает forum.mysite.com

**Просьба II:** Я более-менее понимаю детали, частично въезжаю в регулярки. Ниже представлены доводы и вопросы по шагам. Прокомментируйте, пожалуйста, хотя бы в виде да/нет/смотри там. Можно частично :) Когда я окончательно разберусь, я соберу все в один связный рассказ :)

---

Я начинаю разбирать со строки (6).

**Строка (6)**

Тут у нас условие RewriteCond. 
После пробела идет первый аргумент %{HTTP_HOST}, который сопоставляется регулярному выражению, идущему вторым аргументом. Само регулярное выражение отлавливает домены третьего уровня: text.mysite.com, ru.forum.mysit.com и даже ..mysite.com, а [NC] означает NoCase, т.е. регистронезависимо.

- a) Что такое %{HTTP_HOST}? Что туда попадает?
- б) Какое происходит сопоставление? Проверяется полное соответствие первого аргумента второму? Или, может быть, ищется подстрока, соответствующая второму?
- в) Как в данном случае работают символы **^** в начале регулярного выражения и **$**
     в конце?
- г) [NC] это кусок чего? Регулярного выражения? Или третий аргумент?
- д) Означает ли это, что Test.MySite.com будет обработано точно так же как test.mysite.com ?

**Строка (7)**

Еще одно условие RewriteCond, которое дополняет предыдущее условие отсеиванием www.mysite.com так как в этом случае не надо искать subdmn/www

- е) Каким образом одно условие RewriteCond дополняет другое? Просто порядком? Потому что идут друг за другом?
- ж) Правильно ли я понимаю, что из строк (6) - (9) складывается в каком-то смысле такая конструкция?

  if ( RewriteCond ... )
  else if ( RewriteCond ... )
  else if ( RewriteCond ... )
  { RewriteRule ... }
- з) Как происходит отрицание? Наверное символом **!**, но к чему он относится? К аргументу if`а?
- и) Получается, что можно использовать Сишные логические операторы в синтаксисе .htaccess?

**Строка (8)**

Еще одно условие.

- к) Что содержится в %{REQUEST_URI} ?
- л) Какие конкретно случаи отсекаются в этой строке?

**Строка (9)**

Если мы прошли по строкам (6) - (8) и везде получили истину, то выполняем действие из этой строки (9). И раз это последняя строка, то должно быть тут и просиходит открытие нужной поддирректории. Должно быть ищется то, что в первом аргументе и заменяется вторым.

- м) Что делает регулярное выражение в первом аргументе? Выбирает любые символы в любом количестве? Зачем тут символы **^** и **$**?
- н) Что за комбинация и чего во втором аргументе?
- о) Как работает [L] в данном случае?

**Строка (3)**

Условие, которое проверяется первым делом. Мне думается, что строки (3),(4) это обработка чего-то исключительного, как например код "если полученный аргумент не ноль, то %основной-код%". Навреное это обработка адреса, который напрямую содержит в себе /subdmn/, например mysite.com/subdmn/forum/

- п) регулярка из второго аргумента означает вхождение подстроки /subdmn/ без последующих слешей?
- р) символ **^** в регулярках этой и следующей строк используется как отрицание, не как начало строки?
- с) что проверяется в этой строке?

**Строка (4)**

Самая непонятная срока :)

- т) тут нет символа **$** в конце регулярки. Видимо тут проверяется только то, чтобы строка начиналась с subdmn/, затем шло что-нибудь, но не слеш, затем снова слеш и что угодно. Верно?
- у) /$1 это второй аргумент или конец регулярки?
- ф) что такое [R=permanent,L]
- х) что делает эта строка?
- ц) если выполнится это действие, то исключит ли оно проверку и выполнение других? Другими словами может ли выполнится одновременно действие из строки (4) и из строки (9)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все ответы на ваши вопросы вы можете найти на http://htaccess.net.ru/

**Строка (6)**

- *а)* - переменная сервера, содержит имя текущего домена
- *б)*, *в)* - perl
     совместимое регулярное выражение,
     отсюда всё вытекающее
- *г)*, *д)* - `[NC], nocase` - флаг, устанавливающий
     регистронезависимость выражения.

**Строка (7)**

- *е)* - по идее если не стоит флага `OR` или `AND`, то подразумевается флаг `AND`.
- *ж)* - неправильно, читайте пункт *Ж*.
- *з)* - `знак восклицания(!) или же NOT` инвертируют действие выражения
- *и)* - читаем http://htaccess.net.ru/doc/mod_rewrite/RewriteRule.php

**Строка (8)**

- *к)* - `%{REQUEST_URI}` переменная сервера, содержит имя текущего скрипта вместе с параметрами (по идее)
- *л)* - "если в начале строке нет `subdmn`, то применяем правило"

**Строка (9)**

- *м)* - выбираем всё от начала до конца строки
- *н)* - дальше идет подставление всего выбранного в переменную `%1` и добавляется `%{REQUEST_URI}`
- *о)* - флаг `[L]` указывает, что это последнее правило и после него не применять больше никаких правил преобразований.

**Строка (3)**

- *п)*, *р)* - пункт б)
- *с)* - Если строка попадает под выражение `/subdmn/[^/]`, то согласно выражению `^subdmn/[^/]+/(.*)` получаем переменную `$1`, которая содержит `(.*)`, срабатывает пункт *о)* и отправляются заголовки браузеру о том, что на странице установлен перманентный редирект на страницу `/$1`. Перманентный редирект это же `301` статус (`R=301`)

**Строка (4)**

- *т)* - видимо нет необходимости ставить символ конца строки.
- *у)* - `$1` - это всё то, что содержится в `(.*)`
- *ф)*, *х)*, *ц)* - см пункты *с)*, *о)*

---

Если кто-то нашел ошибки, пишите в комментарии! Ответ должен быть правильным.